# File uploads fail with through web application firewall with mod_security and mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, owasp, mod-security

I've built a Web Application Firewall using Apache 2.4.27 and mod_security 2.9.2. The WAF is stand alone, and forwards requests through to another web server using mod_rewrite with the [P] proxy directive. Everything works fine EXCEPT file uploads.

I've narrowed the file upload problem down to mod_security's `SecRequestBodyAccess` directive. When it's enabled, uploads fail. When it's disabled, they work.

I'm using OWASP's rule set, and I've tried various combinations of mod_security directives and OWASP's rules. Nothing seems to affect the uploads except `SecRequestBodyAccess`.

Problem is, I doubt the security team will allow me to run the WAF without the ability to inspect POST requests (which is the effect of disabling `SecRequestBodyAccess`).

Does anyone know why `SecRequestBodyAccess` breaks uploads and/or how I can fix it?

Here are my mod_security directives:

```
Include owasp-modsecurity-crs/crs-setup.conf
Include owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/*.conf
SecRuleEngine On
SecRequestBodyLimit 262144000
SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 1048576
SecRequestBodyAccess On
SecResponseBodyAccess On
```

Thanks in advance.

-John

Comment: Please provide the log files showing which rule is blocking the upload

Comment: There isn't a rule blocking the uploads. Disabling all rules and/or setting the engine to "DetectionOnly" has no impact. It's returning a 400 error in the logs: "[14/Sep/2017:22:22:42 -0400] "POST /board HTTP/1.1" 400 76"

Comment: And what's in the error logs?